# Magento 2 Customer Grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping

Tags: magento2, customer, import, reindex, memory

I am importing Customer Main file details, I imported 30,000 records and about to reindexing ended up with reindexing issue.

On the first reindexing I got the following error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 291**

So i increased memory limit in my php.ini file from 512M to 2024M.

I also fee up the space in my disk but nothing works.

Any  help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you re indexing from CLI ?

Comment: Yes,  I am indexing from CLI.

Comment: Try php dmemory_limit=5g bin/magento indexer:reindex your indexer name

Comment: have you tried command I shared ?

Answer (score 1):

Please try
Get indexes info

```
php bin/magento indexer:info
```

Check the indexes status

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

Reset all indexes and reindex again

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Or reset just customer grid and reindex again

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid
```

Comment: I have tried this, Its not working. Now I have increased the disk space and also the info.php shows 2024M. Is there any other thing I need to check.

Comment: maybe is another php version used for the cli. Please try php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento indexer:reindex